# Linq InvalidCastException in VB.NET but works in C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I am not VB.NET guy, but I have to right now. I am trying to call a service and get the data back with the VB.NET code below.

But I receive an exception that says **InvalidCastException** *Specified cast is not valid.*

```
Dim service = Ioc.Resolve(Of Services.DokumentServiceClient)()
Dim response = service.Dokument(Id, GroupId, False)
Dim DocumentId = ASPxListBoxDokument.SelectedItem.Value

Dim result = (From documents In response.Values
              From d In documents 
              Where d.DocumentId = DocumentId
              Select d).FirstOrDefault
```

So I tried the same in c# and it works.
This is in C# code

```
var response = client.Dokument(Id, GroupId, false);

Guid DocumentId =  ASPxListBoxDokument.SelectedItem.Value
var result  = (from documents in response.Values
               from d in documents 
               where d.DocumentId == DocumentId 
               select d).FirstOrDefault();
```

What should I do to get it to work in VB.NET?

Comment: This *isn't* the same code though. Where's the type of `client` in the C# code?

Comment: _Where_ did you get that exception? The stacktrace tells you exactly in which line it happened.

Comment: Is it the `Ioc.Resolve` line (i.e. the line that isn't in your c#) that is throwing the exception in your VB code?

Comment: Don't mind the Ioc It is generatet using svcutil. 
The exception is thrown at **.FirstOrDefault***

Comment: Why does the VB code use `service.Dokument` but the C# code uses `client.Dokument`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my VB was that I wasn't converting it to a Guid

```
Dim DocumentId = ASPxListBoxDokument.SelectedItem.Value
```

But in my c# code I was declaring it as Guid

```
Guid DocumentId =  ASPxListBoxDokument.SelectedItem.Value
```

amateur mistake.